# How to prove that ALL records from Query A are present in Table B for millions of records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, large-data

I have query written (in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio V18) which does multiple inner joins to give result set with 3 columns: ZipCode, ID, Income.

This result set contains 118 Million records

I have Table B with 2 columns: ZipCode, ID

Table B contains 123 Million records

These 118M records are present in Table B and I want to prove that.
How do I do this? I don't want another resultset that will display all these 118M records on the output console.

I can add first result set in a temp table but I am stuck after that.
Ideally I would like to see something printed on the console that will say that "All the records from temp table are present in  target table<Table_Name>"

If not, what could be an ideal way to prove that all these records are present in target table?

Comment: Referential integrity constraints? Set-theoretic mathematical axioms?

Comment: SQL includes EXCEPT, INTERSECT and UNION because it's a set-based language. A EXCEPT B shows any A not in B?

Answer (score 0):

so after say you have pushed your query results into temp table say #a, we can proceed like below

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT TOP 1 1
FROM #a A
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
SELECT 1 FROM TableB B
ON A.ZipCode=B.ZipCode 
AND A.Id= B.ID
)
)

BEGIN
PRINT 'All the records from temp table are present in target table<Table_Name>'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH 
TA AS (SELECT ...), --> first query
TB AS (SELECT ...)  --> second query
SELECT * FROM TA
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM TB
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TB
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM TA;
```

Then replace by your queries TA and TB.